# Button action for DataGrid selected rows in WPF with Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have a `DataGrid` and each row has a `Button` which changes a specific column value of row. I am using `Caliburn Micro` and every works perfectly. What I would like to do, is take the `Button` outside of the `DataGrid`. After selecting multiple rows and then pressing just the one `Button, the column value would change just like before, but this time for all the selected rows. Here are a couple of snippets from my current code:

**DataView.xaml:**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Changes" CanUserAddRows="False" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF7F7F7">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn ... />
        <DataGridTextColumn ... />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellCentered}" Header="Validation">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button  Margin="20 0 20 0" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Validated, 
                        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}"                              
                        cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Validate($this)]" Cursor="Hand"
                        cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
                            Validate
                        </Button>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20 0 20 0"
                        Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Validiert, 
                        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}">
                            <TextBlock>Validated</TextBlock>
                            <Button Margin="20 0 0 0" Padding="10 0 10 0" FontSize="25" Foreground="#FF2F5778"                               
                            cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Unvalidate($this)]" Cursor="Hand"
                            cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" >
                                ⮌
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**DataViewModel.cs:**

```
    public void Validate(ChangesModel model)
    {
         model.Validated= true;
         model.ValidateDate = DateTime.Now;
         model.ValidatedBy = LoggedUser.loggedUser;
         db.CheckValidate(model);
    }

    public void Unvalidate(ChangesModel model)
    {
         model.Validated= false;
         model.ValidateDate = null;
         model.ValidatedBy = null;
         db.UnCheckValidate(model);
    }
```

**ChangesModel.cs:**

```
public class ChangesModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _validated;
    public bool Validated
    {
        get { return _validated; }
        set { _validated= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private DateTime? _validatedate;
    public DateTime? ValidateDate
    {
        get { return _validatedate; }
        set { _validatedate= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _validatedBy;
    public string ValidatedBy
    {
        get { return _validatedBy; }
        set { _validatedBy= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion how I would create an action for the `Button` so that it fires the `Validate` method for each selected row of the `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `RowStyle` to bind the `IsSelected` property of the row to a property of your `ChangesModel` class:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected"  Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Then you bind the button to an action that just iterates through the selected models, e.g.:

```
foreach (var model in Changes)
{
    if (model.IsSelected)
    {
        ...
    {
}
```

Comment: Now that the `Button` is outside of the `DataGrid` I bind the action like this: `cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ValidateTest($this)]"` and `cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"` 
In the `ViewModel` : 
`public void ValidateTest()
        {
            foreach (var model in Changes)
            {
                if (model.IsSelected)
                { ... }
            }
        }`
I get an error saying that `ChangesModel` does not have a definition for `IsSelected`

Comment: You need to add the `IsSelected` property to the `ChangesModel` class. It should be a `bool`. You can name it whatever you want.

Comment: Duh! Thanks again for your help mate. I also changed the `Button` action to just this: `cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ValidateTest]"`. It works fine now. Cheers.